# How to set date time format in Logic App

Tags: azure

I have created an API which creates an excel having Date columns too. When I execute the code from local it works well and displays the date as expected.

When I try executing API via Logic App, it changes the date format of that field. How can I set date time in Logic App?

Comment: Add more details about what you're doing and what you want to achieve. Posting the code it will help us to help you.

Comment: CultureInfo ukCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
                               
 DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse("09/07/2017", ukCulture.DateTimeFormat);

Comment: I am changing date format in my code which is displayed correctly when I execute the deployed API. Although when I execute the Logic App which further calls this API, the date format is changed and displayed in US format.

Answer (score 7):

When you have a fixed DateTime-Format you can use the Logic App function "formatDateTime" as follow:

```
formatDateTime(triggerBody()?['myDate'], 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

You can find it under Expressions - Date and Time - "See more" - formatDateTime

Answer (score 2):

I found some useful documentation on Microsoft's site here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/format-datetimefunction

Here it is .. in action:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this to get the current date in GMT format:

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#utcNow

Comment: i havent used this in the above scenarios but based on the documentation the above is the correct way to get the current datetime from dynamic content as an expression:  ahttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#utcNow

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your local machine is running a different [Locale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software)) than the machine running your code when it is deployed.

You could either set the [CultureInfo.CurrentCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) to make sure the right [CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) is used.

CultureInfo...

> Provides information about a specific culture (called a locale for unmanaged code development). The information includes the names for the culture, the writing system, the calendar used, the sort order of strings, and formatting for dates and numbers.

You could also use the appropriate [DateTimeFormatInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), when writing the date to Excel, it

> Provides culture-specific information about the format of date and time values.

Answer (score 0):

Logic apps time zone base on UTC. So, it needs [conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#converttimezone) between UTC to your [local time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones?view=windows-11).

In my case, 'SE Asia Standard Time',    (UTC+07:00);    Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta. So, you need to convert it as your local time. Here's in my case:

[image]

Date `convertTimeZone(utcNow(), 'UTC', 'SE Asia Standard Time', 'MMMM dd, yyyy')`;

Time `convertTimeZone(utcNow(), 'UTC', 'SE Asia Standard Time','hh:mm:ss.ff tt')`